# Passing product data to a cart with modal stage in the middle

Tags: node.js, database, popup, e-commerce, cart

I'm fairly new to node.js and I'm trying to improve my knowledge and skills by building an ecommerce store. I want to have a slightly different UX than the standard ecom store, but I can't figure out how to pass the the data to cart as it seems to 'goes missing' when I add in the extra step.

The journey I'd like is as follows:

User navigates to collection page > clicks on product > opens modal window with product details (mostly for a better look at the image) and here provides an option to add the product to the cart

However, as soon as the modal window is introduced, it seems to default to the first product in the database and adds that instead. The modal also displays the first image rather than the product image that which was clicked and I cannot figure this out to save my life.

When I remove the modal and add the add to cart button to the main page, everything is added to the cart without a problem.

Currently I'm opening the modal client side using jQuery to change the CSS class and I'm fairly certain (in my very limited knowledge) that you can't trigger the modal on click using node.

Can anyone at least point me in the right direction?

```
        <div class="container-fluid body-section">
            <div class="row">


                <% products.forEach(function(product) { %>




                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 collection-col">

                        <img type="input" class="category-thumbnail" src="images/product-images<%= product.image %>"
                            alt="">

                        <div class="collection-icon-container">
                            <span class="fa-regular fa-heart collection-icon heart"></span>

                            <span class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping collection-icon basket"></span>

                        </div>

                        <h3 class="product-card-title">
                            <%= product.name %>
                        </h3>
                        </a>




                    </div>

                    <div id="modal-overlay" class="hidden"></div>

                    <div id="product-modal" class="hidden">

                            <span class="fa-solid fa-x exit"></span>
                            <img id="modal-img" src="images/product-images<%= product.image %>" alt="">
                            <div class="modal-buttons">


                                <form action="/add_to_cart" method="post">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= product.id %>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sku" value="<%= product.sku %>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<%= product.name %>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<%= product.price %>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sale_price" value="<%= product.sale_price %>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" readonly>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="image" value="<%= product.image %>">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark choose-card generic-btn">Choose
                                        card</button>
                                </form>


                                <span class="favourite fa-regular fa-heart"></span>

                            </div>



                    </div>

                    <% }) %>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
$('.category-thumbnail').click( function(event){

    $('body').addClass('overflow');
    $('#product-modal').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#modal-overlay').removeClass('hidden');

});
```

```
app.get('/shop-all',function(req,res) {
    
    var allProducts = mysql.createConnection({
        host:"*********",
        user:"*********",
        password:"********",
        database:"***********"
    });

    allProducts.query("SELECT * FROM products",(err,products)=>{

        res.render('collection',{products:products});
    });

});
```